# trying to read xlrd, extract data, and write csv

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlrd

I am trying to read an excel file, extract some data, and write it out as a csv.  This is pretty new to me and I'm messing up somewhere: I keep getting an empty csv.  I'm sure I'm missing something very basic, but darned if I can see it.  Here is the code:
```
import xlrd
import os
import csv
from zipfile import ZipFile
import datetime

```
datafile = "./2013_ERCOT_Hourly_Load_Data.xls"
outfile = "./2013_Max_Loads.csv"


def parse_file(datafile):

   workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(datafile)
   sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
   data = None
   outputlist = []

   for col in range(1, sheet.ncols):

        cv = sheet.col_values(col, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=None)

        header = sheet.cell_value(0,col)

        maxval = max(cv)

        maxpos = cv.index(maxval) + 1

        maxtime = sheet.cell_value(maxpos, 0)

        realtime = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(maxtime, 0)

        year = realtime[0]

        month = realtime[1]

        day = realtime[2]

        hour = realtime[3]

        data = [
            'Region:', header,
            'Year:', year,
            'Month:', month,
            'Day:', day,
            'Hour:', hour,
             maxpos,
             maxtime,
            realtime,
            maxval,
            ]

    path = "./2013_Max_Loads.csv"
    return outputlist



def save_file(data, filename):

    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
        for line in data:
            writer.writerow(line)

parse_file(datafile)

save_file(parse_file(datafile),"2013_Max_Loads.csv")
```

Comment: What is the `data` you are passing to the `save_file()` function? You should try printing each line to see if it's actually accessing anything.

Comment: If I could make a quick suggestion... Unless you are trying to automate this for a large repository of Excel Workbooks, then you best bet is the do a `File>Save As` in Excel, and save the CSV from their.

Comment: **General Comment:** How do you reject a Tag Edit when the Tag is for a Python Module that the Question specifically asks about? Tags are used not only as descriptors but also as filters for searches. If the topic of the post is about a specific topic that the OP did not include the tag for, then there should be no way that a Tag Edit that adds that adds that tag is rejected. **XLRD** has very specific syntax and functionality and including that tag is import as someone with expertise on the function may review as a result of the tag and find something missed by other responders.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `outfile` but you don't use it

You aren't passing a directory (path) for the file to be saved in.

I also think that calling `parse_file` twice might be messing you up. Just pass the filename and call it from within the `save_file` function.

I also found that you were returning `output list` as a blank list.

So here, try this. I will assume your `xlrd` commands are correct, because I have not personally used the module.

```
import csv

import xlrd


def parse_file(datafile):

   workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(datafile)
   sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
   outputlist = []
   outputlist_append = outputlist.append

   for col in range(1, sheet.ncols):
        cv = sheet.col_values(col, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=None)
        header = sheet.cell_value(0,col)
        maxval = max(cv)
        maxpos = cv.index(maxval) + 1
        maxtime = sheet.cell_value(maxpos, 0)
        realtime = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(maxtime, 0)
        year = realtime[0]
        month = realtime[1]
        day = realtime[2]
        hour = realtime[3]

        data = [
            'Region:', header,
            'Year:', year,
            'Month:', month,
            'Day:', day,
            'Hour:', hour,
             maxpos,
             maxtime,
            realtime,
            maxval,
            ]
        outputlist_append(data)

    return outputlist


def save_file(data, filename):

    parse_file(data)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
        for line in data:
            writer.writerow(line)
    return


datafile = "./2013_ERCOT_Hourly_Load_Data.xls"
outfile = "./2013_Max_Loads.csv"

save_file(datafile, outfile)
```

> **UPDATE: Edit in code in function `save_file()` to implement @wwii's suggestion.**

**Try substituting the new `save_file()` below:**

```
def save_file(data, filename):

    parse_file(data)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
        wr.writerows(data)
    return
```

Also, change the variable (you used `writer`) to something like `wr`. You really want to avoid any possible conflicts with having a variable with the same name as a method, a function, or class you are calling.

Comment: The documentation for `csv.writer()` on python.org is inconsistent on whether to open the file as `'wb'` or `'w'`. For Py2.X it is `'wb'` and for Py3.X it is `'w'`. So make the adjustment for whichever version of Python you are running this on.

Comment: No need to iterate over ```data```:  ```writer.writerows(data)```.

Comment: @wwii True. Good call, My edit tried to leave the OP's form as intact as possible while hopefully fixing the functions, but that is definitely a good point.

Comment: I have made the changes suggested by @AMR and I think they are definitely pointing me in the right direction, but I'm still having and odd problem.  If I simply run "parse_file" after declaring datafile and outfile, I get roughly the result I'm after in outputlist- certainly close enough to work with. That is '''[['Region:',
  u'COAST',
  'Year:',
  2013,
  'Month:',
  8,
  'Day:',
  13,
  'Hour:',
  17,
  5392,
  41499.708333333336,
  (2013, 8, 13, 17, 0, 0),
  18772.772393999992]]''' However, the save_file function produces an empty file.  Again, I'm missing something very fundamental here.

Comment: @BrianM, as you've said that `parse_file`'s `outputlist` gives you something that looks to be about correct, I have added an update to incorporate a suggestion by **wwii** from the comments. He is correct that using the `writerows` method is the right way to go, and there may be something inherent to the `csv` module that doesn't like writing out lines from loops. You also haven't mentioned which version of Python you are running. Python.org had a difference in how they opened a file name between py2.7 and py.3, so I think it would be worth noting as you may also want to change `'wb'` to `'w'`

Comment: OK, here comes a real dumb question:  I have made all the suggested changes.  They are helping tremendously (THANKS!!)  but I seem to be having what I'm guessing is a scope issue.  Here is all the code:

Comment: `def save_file(data, filename):

    parse_file(data)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
        wr.writerows(data)
    return`  I get a 'name 'outputlist' is not defined' error.  (btw: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Are you really trying to save it to the root directory, or was that just for illustrative purposes.? Because I have been wondering if that may not be the issue. Try changing the path to a user directory that you know that you are absolutely sure that you have write access to and then try it. Also type out the entire path. If that isn't it, then I am stumped.

Comment: Also try taking out delimiter. Get it to work with the default argument (',') and then see if you can add it back in. And for the heck of it, just use `'w'` instead of `'wb'`, Just do it one at a time. First take out the `b`. If that doesn't work, but it back and take out the `delimiter`. And if that doesn't work. take out both `delimiter` and the `b`.